# Excel 2007 data refresh that used to work with sheet protected

Tags: excel, vba

We have just moved from excel 2003 to 2007 and I wrote this code to refresh a data connection then use the results for various bits.
The problem is if I run through it by pressing F8 it works but when the macro is run by itself I get an error about the cells being protected even though my code contains a Unprotected and protect macro.

```
Sub code()
UnPro 'Macro to Unprotected worksheet 
Dim p As Integer
Dim q As Integer
Dim lastnew As Long
Dim LastOld As Long
Dim pctCompl As Single
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

pctCompl = 5 'Update Progress Bar
progress pctCompl 'Update Progress Bar

'Range("A6").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").Refresh

pctCompl = 10 'Update Progress Bar
progress pctCompl 'Update Progress Bar


p = 0
q = 0

Do Until q = 1
    If Sheets("Main").Range("G4").Offset(p, 0).Text <> "" Then
        p = p + 1
    Else
        q = 1
        lastnew = p + 3
    End If
Loop

x = 0
y = 0

pctCompl = 50 'Update Progress Bar
progress pctCompl 'Update Progress Bar

Do Until y = 1
    If Sheets("Main").Range("H4").Offset(x, 0).Value <> "" Then
        x = x + 1
    Else
        y = 1
        LastOld = x + 3
    End If
Loop

pctCompl = 70 'Update Progress Bar
progress pctCompl 'Update Progress Bar

If LastOld <> lastnew Then
    Range(Cells(LastOld - 1, 8), Cells(LastOld - 1, 8)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LastOld - 1, 8), Cells(lastnew, 8)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End If

pctCompl = 100 'Update Progress Bar
progress pctCompl 'Update Progress Bar
ProgBar.Hide
ProTe 'Macro to Protected worksheet 
End Sub
```

I have tried to us DoEvents after the `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").Refresh` but that did not work.
also I don't want to use a wait really because sometimes there may be 10 new lines and others the may be thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the properties of the connection so that it doesn't refresh in the background. That will force the code to wait while it refreshes before continuing.